# Transforming a claim using multiple match RegEx

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

I'm working on connecting our on prem AD with AWS by following this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enabling-federation-to-aws-using-windows-active-directory-adfs-and-saml-2-0/).  We have our AD Groups that are to be translated into AWS groups written in the format AWS#Account#Role#AccountNumber in AD.  In ADFS, I am writing a custom claim that is to take that particular claim and convert it to the arn that requires the role and account number that is defined in teh AD Group name.  I was hoping to use a RegExReplace with a match type of ((?i)([-_a-z0-9]+) which should accurately give me multiple matches back from the incoming token.

My question is, is there a way that I can use the multiple matches generated there to generate one string ("arn:aws:iam::saml-provider/ADFS,arn:aws:iam::role/")that leverages the multiple matches to generate the AWS format I need?

I dont normally work with ADFS but this is something I was tasked to figure out and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Roles rule (executes after the gathering of AD Groups rule), I updated my claims rule language transform to:

```
c:[Type=="http://temp/variable", 
Value=~"(?i)(^AWS)#([-_a-z0-9]+)#([-_a-z0-9]+)#([-_a-z0-9]+)"] => 
issue(Type="https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role", 
Value=RegExReplace(c.Value, 
                   "(?i)(^AWS)#(?<accountname>[-_a-z0-9]+)#(?<role>[-_a-z0-9]+)#(?<accountnumber>[-a-z0-9]+)", 
                   "arn:aws:iam:${accountnumber}:saml-provider/ADFS,arn:aws:iam:${accountnumber}:role/${role}))
```

This basically says, for any AD Group that was added the to the temp variable and matches this regex, issue a claim of this type.  In the RegExReplace, I assigned variable names to the grouping matches and then accessed those matches using the ${} syntax.  This did the trick and now I see the list of roles in the arn format.